# Two buttons one form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, dom-events

```
<?=form_open('blog/register');?> 
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="register_name">Username : </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="register_name" readonly="readonly" value="<?=$_POST['username']?>"/></td>                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="register_email">Email:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="register_email" readonly="readonly" value="<?=$_POST['email']?>"/></td>                
                </tr>                
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="register_password">Password:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="register_password" readonly="readonly" value="<?=$_POST['password']?>"/></td>                
                </tr>               
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="return true;"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>                     
                        <input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="window.location.replace('http://localhost/index.php?username='<?=$_POST['username']?>'&email='<?=$_POST['email']?>');return true;"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?=form_close()?>
```

That is the form with two buttons as two choices, the Register button is to redirect the user to the registered screen whereas the second button will direct him to the logon screen. It doesn't work, could someone offer me a hint or any instructions please ?

I click the second button and nothing happens. The first button works fine

Comment: what does "it doesn't work" mean? What does it do now, and what should it do in your opinion?

Comment: Okay, I update it for better clarity

Comment: You're using tables. You shouldn't use tables for layout. Every time your code runs God kills a kitten. I hope you're happy.

Comment: @Truth maybe he like kittens fried .) but anyway, user1211355 what's the output from error console? I'll bet you a beer that you have your answer in your javascript error console and you just didn't check it :)

Comment: @Vyktor I guess you just earned yourself a nice cold beer. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing

```
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="window.location.replace('http://localhost/index.php?username='<?=$_POST['username']?>'&email='<?=$_POST['email']?>');return true;"/>
```

with

```
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://localhost/index.php?username=<?=$_POST['username']?>&email=<?=$_POST['email']?>';return true;"/>
```

I believe you have some quotes mixed up.

To clarify, I removed the single quotes around your php because I believe they aren't necessary and cut off your location string at a place you don't want.
The location string that your code produces is `'http://localhost/index.php?username='`, which is incorrect.

**UPDATE**
Changed `replace()` to `href`

Comment: Why are you suggesting `replace()` http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp he uses only one param... it should be `windows.location.href=`, no? (Just asking) and I've got a feeling that you forgot ' at the end of function call

Comment: But it doesn't resolve my problem at all, I press the second button it remains the same no thing javascript method is called

Comment: @Vyktor, good suggestion, I changed my answer. `href` is indeed the way to go. I just noted the quotes issue and corrected that, but indeed `replace` is not the correct function call either. Note, that it is what user1211355 used, not directly my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code

```
 <input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="window.location.replace('http://localhost/index.php?username='<?=$_POST['username']?>'&email='<?=$_POST['email']?>');return true;"/>
```

with

```
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="window.location.replace('http://localhost/index.php?username=<?=$_POST['username']?>&email=<?=$_POST['email']?>');return true;"/>
```